# paintComponent method is not drawing image

Tags: java, graphics, paintcomponent, drawimage

I am trying to get used to using the `paintComponent()` method before I incorporate it into my program. However, whenever I try and draw an image to the `JPanel`, it is not working. I have put the code below. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
public class ExperimentGame extends JPanel{

Image image;

public ExperimentGame(){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(this);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setSize(500,500); //my edit
    this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    try {
        image = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource("spaceship (0).png"));
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawImage(image, 50, 50, null);
}
}

public class ExperimentMain {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ExperimentGame game = new ExperimentGame();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A small hack to solve your problem is to call at the bottom of your constructor.

```
this.revalidate();
this.repaint();
```

However I recommend you to take a look how Model-View-Controller can be used to update your view whenever something is changed in your model. An example can be found [here](http://www.austintek.com/mvc/).

Comment: Why is it that at all the tutorials I've looked at, they don't use the lines of code you suggest and yet their program runs fine?

Comment: It worked, but from what I understand, this shouldn't be necessary to add.

Comment: @jmao Those lines should not be necessary.  If adding them makes a difference, you probably need to obey [Swing threading rules](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and change your `main` method to `EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> new ExperimentGame());`, which forces your code to run in the AWT event dispatch thread.

Comment: Kind of odd, but when I did what you said and then commented out the above two lines, the images don't display until I drag the window to a larger size. Do you know why that's the case?

Comment: Oh, wait the same thing happens when I just comment out the above two lines without making the change you recommend, so I don't think your recommendation did anything.